# SQL query to set values as null if not found in the link table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have checked a few threads in stackoverflow, but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

I have 3 tables, the third one is a link table.

```
Table1:         |  Table2:                  |  LinkTable:
ID  Value       |  ID   Value1    Value2    |  Table1_ID Table2_ID
a       aa      |  p    pp        ppp       |  a         p
b       bb      |  q    qq        qqq       |  b         r
c       bb      |  r    rr        rrr       |
```

I used the query:

```
SELECT t1.Value t1Value, t2.Value1 t2Value1, t2.Value2 t2Value2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN LinkTable lt ON lt.Table1_ID = t1.ID
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = lt.Table2_ID
```

which returns a table:

```
t1Value  t2Value1  t2Value2
aa       pp        ppp
bb       rr        rrr
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
Result:    
t1Value  t2Value1  t2Value2
aa       pp        ppp
bb       rr        rrr
cc       NULL      NULL <=i.e. if the Table1 ID is not linked to Table2 ID the values should be null (or white-space)
```

How can this be done in SQL?

Thanks.

PS: What I am doing now is, I am using 2 different queries (one is mentioned above and another for the nulls), but I am looking for a single query.

Comment: You tagged this with `sql-server` **and** `mysql` what are you really using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: oh sorry, sql-server.

Comment: i think you need a  `left join`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `left outer join`:

```
SELECT t1.Value t1Value, t2.Value1 t2Value1, t2.Value2 t2Value2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN LinkTable lt ON lt.Table1_ID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = lt.Table2_ID;
```

Comment: +1; You gotta love these questions, it's almost like breathing!